# pyPdf: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Tags: python, pdf, decode, utf-16, pypdf

I have a pdf file that breaks pyPdf: http://tovotu.de/tests/test.pdf

This is the sample script:

```
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

outputPdf = PdfFileWriter()

inpdf = open("test.pdf","rb")
inputPdf = PdfFileReader(inpdf)
[outputPdf.addPage(x) for x in inputPdf.pages]

with open("output.pdf","wb") as outpdf:
    outputPdf.write(outpdf)
```

Error output is here: http://pastebin.com/0m38zhjQ

The error is the same when using PyPDF2 from GitHub. pdftk can handle this pdf just like any other pdf out there. Please note, that writing fails, but reading seems to work just fine!

Can you at least point me to the exact part of the pdf that causes that error? A workaround would be even nicer :)

Comment: I tried downloading the PDF but that service rushed me from one unwanted file to the next.

Comment: Okay, I changed the link to something more straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in PyPDF2. In [this section](https://github.com/knowah/PyPDF2/blob/2857d4825ce217d74bb1a2c893940bc3083dda9b/PyPDF2/generic.py#L256):

```
if string.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF16_BE):
    retval = TextStringObject(string.decode("utf-16"))
    retval.autodetect_utf16 = True
```

it assumes that any string starting with (0xFE, 0xFF) can be decoded as UTF-16. Your file contains a bytestring that begins that way but then contains invalid UTF-16.

The simplest fix is to comment out that `if` and unconditionally use the `# This is probably a big performance hit here` branch.

Comment: Actually that assumption is Ok for strings **outside of streams:** they come in 2 different flavors which can be recognized by that BOM. Unfortunately this method is also used here for strings **inside of streams** whose encoding follows completely different rules and is determined by the PDF font objects. Thus, a complete fix includes separating code paths for those two cases even here.

Comment: In fact, it appears that a recent version of PyPDF2 (1.16) attempts to fix this problem: https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/commit/e4d6ebcdb7e3b233e581ebeeaa32686dd5e1fed0